# Binding to "IsExpanded" not working for root node in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, treeview

I have a `TreeView` that will display several different datatypes in an arbitrary hierarchy.  To accomplish this, I'm defining specific `HierarchicalDataTemplate`'s for each datatype that will be diplayed in my `TreeView`:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyFirstType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsObjectExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MySecondType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyThirdType}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
    ...
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Each `HierarchicalDataTemplate` will have a slightly different style (not shown above), which is why I'm defining different `HierarchicalDataTemplate`'s for each type.

The `IsExpanded` binding isn't working the way I expect, however.  The root node of the `TreeView` is never expanded, regardless of the value of the source object's `IsObjectExpanded` property.  The child node bindings are working as expected.

In addition, if I hardcode the `IsExpanded` property to `True` in the root node's `HierarchicalDataTemplate` definition (assuming I know which type will be at the root of the tree), its *children* show up expanded rather than the root node itself.

Am I using the `IsExpanded` property correctly?  Or is there another way I should be setting the `IsExpanded` property in order to include the root node?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle` sets style for **children** of the item you declare template for. If you need to set style for the root, you can use `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle`.

If you feel restricted by this architecture (which is admittedly silly), you can use `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyleSelector`.